# Convert List<List<String>> to ArrayList<String> in Android

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, type-conversion

I want to convert them to ArrayList and I will store them. After that, I have to convert them into old values. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
public List<List<String>> phones = new ArrayList<>();
public List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>(); 

public ArrayList<String> phones = ?
public ArrayList<String> menus = ?
```

Comment: are you using java-8?

Comment: so you need to flat the list?

Comment: I am using android. Java can help for that. Any solution can help :) I want to convert List<List to ArrayList after that, I will convert Arraylist to List<List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used gson to solve it. I share a sample.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<String> gsonString = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<restaurants.size(); i++)
        gsonString.add(gson.toJson(restaurants.get(i)));
// Store it
tinydb.putListString("tinyRestaurant",gsonString);
```

And convert again

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
for(int i=0; i<tinydb.getListString("tinyRestaurant").size(); i++)
            restaurants.add(gson.fromJson(tinydb.getListString("tinyRestaurant").get(i), Restaurant.class));
```

Answer (score 3):

For the first scenario, you can flatten the phones nested list into a single list and then collect into an `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<String> result = 
                  phones.stream()
                        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

For the second scenario, you will need to extract the string representation of the `Menu` objects given you've overridden `toString`, otherwise you'll need to extract some type of property from the `Menu` objects in order to project from `Menu` to `String`.

Given you've overridden `toString`, then do it this way:

```
ArrayList<String> menuResult = 
                  menus.stream()
                       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                       .map(Menu::toString)
                       .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Given you need to extract some property from menus, then do it this way:

```
ArrayList<String> menuResult = 
                  menus.stream()
                       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                       .map(Menu::getName)
                       .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

If your API level doesn't support these features then you can use:

```
// flatten List<List<String>> to ArrayList<String>
ArrayList<String> phonesAccumulator = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<String> temp : phones) {
     phonesAccumulator.addAll(temp);
}

// flatten List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> to ArrayList<String>
ArrayList<String> menusAccumulator = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<Restaurant.Menu> temp : menus) {
    for(Restaurant.Menu m : temp){
       menusAccumulator.add(m.toString());
       // or m.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: It can work but it gives api level problem in android.

Comment: Thank you for first part. Can you convert ArrayList to List<List ?

Comment: `List<List<String>> menusAccumulator = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Restaurant.Menu> temp : menus) {
            List<String> tempAccumulator = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Restaurant.Menu m : temp){
                tempAccumulator.add(m.toString());
                // or m.getName();
            }
            menusAccumulator.add(tempAccumulator);
        }` ?

Comment: Sorry, there is a problem in this code. I want to convert menusAccumulator to List<List<Restaurant.Menu>>  menus in this time;

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, flatMap can be useful here:

```
ArrayList<String> phoneList = phones.stream()
                                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am proving my resolution as below said, so you can change as per your own -

```
    List<String> nonvegList = new ArrayList<String>();
    nonvegList.add("Mutton Keema");
    nonvegList.add("Chicken Keema");
    nonvegList.add("Korma Veg Keema");
    nonvegList.add("Pulaav Biryaani");
    nonvegList.add("Mutton Biryaani");
    nonvegList.add("Chicken Biryaani");

    List<List<String>> menuList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    menuList.add(nonvegList);

    ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>(menuList.get(0));
    System.out.println(resultList);
```

sweet, simple and in understadable format, compatible after Java 6+,

hope this will help you, thanks.

Comment: I guess you create new ArrayList for each list(row). If list is too long, it will be problem.

Comment: see, you already have a list, and I have just given the 7 lines of code for your understanding right, I can also write these kind of things in single line, so here you have many menu list like vegList, nonvegList, iceCreamList, snacksList etc. added to your menuList (List<List<String>>) and you can easily declare an arrayList object and put the values collection by the time of initialization.

Comment: Sorry, can you edit your post and can you add code? My mind confused a bit. How can I get all values in once.

Comment: Here before converting the list collection to the class ArrayList, JVM first initializes the ArrayList<String> from the existing List<String> object in the ArrayList<String> constructor part, and thus initializing the resultList variable and this is just possible because the Collection is a super class for both type List and ArrayList, I think I have explained, if found helpful mark this as answer.